# How to load one controller action in other phtml file, in Zend

Tags: zend-framework

I have a controller 'test' with action 'index'.

Now i need to load another controller action in this  index.phtml

for example index(controller) & add(action)

How can i do that?

Comment: do u want to change the phtml ?]

Comment: yea.in one controller action, i creating the common menus.So i need this menus in other phtml file

Comment: can you share the code that u have tried so that i will get a clear picture of what you are tryingf

Comment: Have you used `$this->partial()` [Rendering Partials in Other Modules](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html)

Answer (score 0):

in your controller you can use the following code to change the controller and action

```
$this->_forward('someaction', 'somecontroller');
```

to include another phtml from view you should use following code in your phtml

```
<?php  echo $this->render("somecontroller/common.phtml");?>
```

If you want to use some common function in some controller keep it separate and call from every action

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But i need to load other controller action in .phtml file, not in controller